# How to alter postgres column data type using hibernate query

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

The alter column data type syntax in postgresql is :

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
ALTER COLUMN column_name 
TYPE newType USING (column_name::newType)
```

I'm trying to use it via hibernate's SQLQuery to manage some dynamically created tables. The problem is hibernate sees `::newType` as being parameters and throws a parameter not found error, and if I don't use casting postgres throws another error asking me to cast the type.

Is there any way of achieving this via hibernate?

Comment: have you tried with `USING (column_name\\:\\:newType)`? I think i have seen sth like this before

Comment: @Apostolos It works. I tried looking up the hibernate escape character but couldn't find it, I never assumed it would be just the basic java escape. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please escape the `::` like this

```
USING (column_name\\:\\:newType)
```